# How do I prevent a textbox's width from growing outside its container?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to allow a textbox to grow in size, until it fills its container. If you place a blank textbox on a WPF window, it will increase in size (as a user types text into it) until it fills the container, at which point it will stop expanding in size.

However, if I place that textbox in a grid, the textbox never ceases to grow. And even stranger, if I hardcode some fixed widths on the grid's columns, the textbox will even STILL continue to grow.

I want the textbox to grow, and the grid to grow, but once the grid cannot grow anymore, I want the textbox to stop growing also. Can this be done?

---

Here's a quick sample. As you type into the textbox, it'll grow in size (as intended). However, the textbox will continue to grow even after the grid is completely filled the WPF form.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="window">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="StackOverflow"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you provide the xaml to reproduce this issue?

Comment: what about wrapping the text?

Comment: Does changing the second ColumnDefinition to <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> provide the behavior you're expecting?

Answer (score 4):

Setting the second column definition's width to "*" should provide you with the desired functionality.

In addition, set the `MinWidth` on the textbox, and the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Left`, so that it doesn't stretch to the column width.  If you want it to stretch, then remove this property.

In this example, I added an additional column with a width of 50 to highlight that the textbox will stop growing once it meets the column width boundary.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />    
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                Text="StackOverflow" />

    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                MinWidth="50" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Something must be overriding the default behaviors (my grid is nested in a tabcontrol). My TextBox doesn't fill the space (although it does in the sample I provided) when I use "*", any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any global styles applied to your textbox?

Comment: afaik TextBoxes normally dont fill the space. Use `HorizontalAlignment=Stretch` to get that behavior

Comment: @Dominik, HorizontalAlignment is defaulted to stretch, because it's inherited from the parent element (grid column).  When a parent is not defined, it inherits it's value from the FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment property, which defaults to stretch.